# Error: Cannot find module 'pg', after running npm install pg

Tags: node.js, pg

Using VSCode. Installed latest Node.js (first time user) for Windows, and the desired modules, one of which was 'pg' (npm install pg)

At the top of my script I have this:
`const pg = require('pg');`

When i attempt to debug, I get this error when it hits that line:

```
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\EBI\Work\Node-pg-log\get_pg_log.js:3:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:649:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Is there something else I need to install or set up? Debugging is in place.

Comment: Is it only when debugging is in place, and only that module? Just trying to get a sense of the situation.

Comment: Happens in regular run mode as well. And it seems to be all modules I'm trying to use.

Comment: do you have `node_modules` folder in your project root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually happens when `node_modules/` folder is located in some sub-directory. Like

```
/app
----index.js
----/libs
--------/node_modules/
```

You want a directory structure like

```
/app
----index.js
----node_modules/
```

Where `node_modules` folder is either in the current directory or in some upper level directory

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript it is necessary to install pg types.  Use the command

```
npm install --save-dev @types/pg
```

Comment: its not about pg type, this commands help me  "npm install pg --save"

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with Strapi 4, we fixed it by installing `pg`:

> If you get a “cannot find module ‘pg’” error, install it by running `yarn add pg` or `npm install --save pg`

As written here: https://strapi.io/blog/postgre-sql-and-strapi-setup